# Programmatically creating a hyperlink in an email to link to a specific folder in SharePoint

Tags: email, folder, hyperlink

I have a VB.Net application which uses the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client to upload/download documents from a SharePoint site. What my client now needs is for the application to create an email which contains a hyperlink to a specific folder on the SharePoint site. This folder will vary each time and the email will be used on phones or tablets by engineers (the folder contains their work documents). The engineers can access SharePoint but with so many folders, one per job, then they need a simple method to access their documents.

I reckon that I need the URL of the folder but all I can get is the relative folder (using listItem("FileDirRef") ) e.g. /sites/engineers/shared documents and not the absolute reference e.g. https: // company.sharepoint.com/:f:/s/Engineers/1234567890ABCDEFG-xyzab-1234tyh90?e=OT9PI0

Should be simple but...
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

One of my client's staff said that they used the Copy Link facility in SharePoint and emailed a couple of samples. The first link was I expected with the encrypted reference to the folder. However the second link was in plain text and from it I was able to determine the correct format.

It all works fine now.